# Spring Boot 2.4.4 failed to start after upgrading

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, spring-vault

I am upgrading Spring boot application, which is currently working on 2.1.13 to 2.4.4.
After upgrade, spring boot application is not starting.
Few of the modules used in application are as follows:

- spring-cloud-sleuth
- spring-cloud-starter-zipkin
- spring-cloud-vault-config

  Below is the detail stack trace:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'braveHttpServerHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/instrument/web/BraveHttpBridgeConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'braveHttpServerHandler' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'httpTracing' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/brave/instrument/web/BraveHttpConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'httpTracing' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sleuthSkipPatternProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/instrument/web/SkipPatternConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.SkipPatternProvider]: Factory method 'sleuthSkipPatternProvider' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultHealthIndicatorConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'vaultTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration$ClientFactoryWrapper]: Factory method 'clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration.<init>(Lorg/springframework/vault/support/SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration;Lorg/springframework/vault/support/SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.tracingFilter(TraceWebServletConfiguration.java:125)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.init(TraceWebServletConfiguration.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5203)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at com.ifds.kea.web.WebAppConfig.main(WebAppConfig.java:20)
```

Any suggestion or guidance on above issue is appreciated.

POM files:

1. parent pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.27</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <commons-collections4.version>4.4</commons-collections4.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.12.0</commons-lang3.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.8.0</commons-io.version>
        <cxf.version>3.4.2</cxf.version>
        <findbugs-annotations.version>3.0.1</findbugs-annotations.version>
        <guava.version>30.1-jre</guava.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.45</mysql.version>
        <odata.version>4.8.0</odata.version>
        <redisson.version>3.15.1</redisson.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-security-oauth2.version>2.5.0.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
        <spring-security-rsa.version>1.0.9.RELEASE</spring-security-rsa.version>
        <swagger.version>1.6.2</swagger.version>
        <swagger2.version>3.0.0</swagger2.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.15.2</testcontainers.version>
        <togglz.version>2.9.6</togglz.version>
        <vavr.version>0.10.3</vavr.version>
        <wiremock.version>2.27.2</wiremock.version>
        <xmlunit.version>1.6</xmlunit.version>
        <junit-vintage-engine.version>5.7.0</junit-vintage-engine.version>

        <!-- required until KN-3761 is fixed -->
        <httpasyncclient.version>4.1.2</httpasyncclient.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.2</httpclient.version>
        <groovy.version>3.0.6</groovy.version>
        <spock.version>2.0-M4-groovy-3.0</spock.version>
        <objenesis.version>3.1</objenesis.version>
        <embedded-redis.version>0.6</embedded-redis.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-collections4.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>${guava.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
                <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
                <version>${vavr.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
                <artifactId>odata-client-core</artifactId>
                <version>${odata.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger2.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
                <artifactId>redisson-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${redisson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security-rsa.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${findbugs-annotations.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>info.solidsoft.spock</groupId>
                <artifactId>spock-global-unroll</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
                <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
                <version>${objenesis.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
                <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
                <version>${wiremock.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                <version>${junit-vintage-engine.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

2. micro-service pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.27</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>test-microservice-pom</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.20</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.getsentry.raven</groupId>
            <artifactId>raven-logback</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

1. My application pom (Application which running)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-microservice-pom</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.20</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>web-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-${build.number}</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-common-api</artifactId>
            <version>${test-common-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
            <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>odata-client-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
            <artifactId>togglz-junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

2. test-common-api (lib)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.27</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.test.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-common-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.20</version>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-vault-config</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

Comment: Did you also update Spring Cloud?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes, below are the details: 
   spring-cloud-sleuth-core : 2.2.7.RELEASE
spring-cloud-starter-zipkin : 2.1.3.RELEASE 
spring-cloud-dependencies : 2020.0.2

Comment: can you please post the whole pom.xml

Comment: @SimonMartinelli sure, our application is using parent pom, and also we have several different libraries. I will attach all the Pom file. Thanks

Comment: @SimonMartinellii  I have added pom files details, i had made few changes  to upload, due max character allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining a lot of versions on your own (you should not), also using old dependencies that are not available anymore (fyi: the current Sleuth version is 3.0.x), e.g.:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

As the [docs suggest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-set-up-sleuth-with-brave-zipkin-http), you should not use version numbers so that the BOM can define them and you should use the right dependencies:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
              <version>${release.train-version}</version>
              <type>pom</type>
              <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Please notice the difference between your dependency: `spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:2.1.3.RELEASE` and the ones you should use: `spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin` and `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth`.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot 2.7.0 and Cloud 2021.0.3

add bean

```
@Bean
public Sampler defaultSampler() {
    return Sampler.ALWAYS_SAMPLE;
}
```

If you used an example like this it will give the same error.

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Bean
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```